# How to check if NUMA is enabled on my Solaris machine, and then enable it if not?

Tags: solaris, numa

How to check if NUMA is enabled on my Solaris machine, and then enable it if not?

I have `Solaris 11 11/11 SPARC`

I tried `sudo find /proc|grep -i numa` but it prints nothing

Comment: On Solaris, `/proc/` only contains information about running processes - it does not include the system configuration information that Linux does.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris handles NUMA machines by grouping processors and memory into *logical groups* (*lgrp*). You may use [`lgrpinfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/820-1691/gesuq/index.html) to check that:

```
myaut@sfx4600:~$ lgrpinfo
lgroup 0 (root):
        Children: 1 2
        CPUs: 0-7
        Memory: installed 4,0G, allocated 983M, free 3,0G
        Lgroup resources: 1 2 (CPU); 2 (memory)
        Latency: 12
lgroup 1 (leaf):
        Children: none, Parent: 0
        CPUs: 0-3
        Lgroup resources: 1 (CPU);
        Load: 0,386
lgroup 2 (leaf):
        Children: none, Parent: 0
        CPUs: 4-7
        Memory: installed 4,0G, allocated 983M, free 3,0G
        Lgroup resources: 2 (CPU); 2 (memory)
        Load: 0,199
        Latency: 10
myaut@sfx4600:~$ lgrpinfo -Ta
0
|-- 1
|   CPUs: 0-3
|   Load: 0,288
`-- 2
    CPUs: 4-7
    Memory: installed 4,0G, allocated 982M, free 3,0G
    Load: 0,128
    Latency: 10
```

See more here: https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/locality_group_observability_on_solaris